# Finding $n$-dimensional vector direction

Tags: geometry, vectors

Given that the direction of vector $\boldsymbol v$ can be found using:

$$\boldsymbol w = \Bigl(\frac{v_1}{\|v\|}, \frac{v_2}{\|v\|}\Bigr) $$

Would it follow that the direction of $n$-dimensional vector $\boldsymbol y$ can be found with the following?

$$\boldsymbol w = \Bigl(\frac{y_1}{\|y\|}, \frac{y_2}{\|y\|}, \dots, \frac{y_n}{\|y\|}\Bigr) $$

Any documentation/articles explaining the above would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure whether one follows from the other, but yes: both are correct

Comment: Yes, in fact what you're calling a "direction" is really the unit vector for which $w$ is a positive multiple.

Comment: That gives a unit vector pointing in the same direction as the original vector.  Is that what you mean by "finding the direction of the vector"?

Comment: @user247327 Yes, I was under the impression that I could use the term "direction" as a way to describe the resulting new vector. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you mean by a direction vector is a new vector which is parallel to the original vector, and that has unit length. In this case, yes this is how to write an $n$ dimensional unit vector, because you want $\|w\|=1$, and this holds for the vector you have written, $$w = \Bigl(\frac{y_1}{\|y\|}, \frac{y_2}{\|y\|}, \dots, \frac{y_n}{\|y\|}\Bigr)$$ We have $$\|w\|^2=w\cdot w=\frac1{\|y\|^2}({y_1}^2+{y_2}^2+{y_3}^2+\cdots+{y_n}^2)=\frac1{\|y\|^2}y\cdot y=1$$

Since $\|w\|\ge 0$, square rooting gives $\|w\|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\|\mathbf v\| $ is a scalar that is always greater than $0.$  (unless $\bf v$ is the zero vector, in which case is also does not have direction.)

$\frac {\mathbf v}{\|\mathbf v\|} $ is a scalar multiple of $\bf v.$

All vector spaces have scalar multiplication.

Scalar multiplication by a positive scalar does not change direction.